# Using Java's default package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

In Eclipse, when I start a new Project, I go through the wizard, and when I get to writing my first class for that project I am asked to select a package. Sometimes out of laziness I just choose the default package.

The wizard warns me this is discouraged. Even if I ignore the warnings I never have any problems with the application due to this. Or at least, so far I have never had any problem.

So why does Eclipse want me to create a new package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse, and most other IDEs, are geared towards large projects.  Hobbyist programming and small-scale assignments can get by in IDEs often, but be aware that the general assumption would be for larger projects - anything between 10 and 5,000+ classes.

There is also a chance that you create a class which has a similar name to something in the Java API - for example:

- [`java.rmi.MarshalException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/MarshalException.html) and
- [`javax.xml.bind.MarshalException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/MarshalException.html)

Ambiguity in instantiating the class (`throw new MarshalException();`) if both classes exist on the same classpath is a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't import classes from the default package. I understand it's allowed as a convenience or for very small (one class file) tasks.